# Pandas create separate df's thru iterate thru existing df rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'animal': ['Cow', 'Mouse', 'Horse', 'Dog', 'Cat'], 
        'age': [12, 1, 23, 4, 5], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'id': [234, 745, 732, 245, 232]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

How could I iterate thru each row in the pandas df and create a seperate df based off of each row? For example I can iterate thru each row as shown below and print `animal` column, but ultimately I am trying to figure out how to iterate each row and create a separate `df` of each row and the `df` name would be the `animal` row value.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    print(row['animal'])
```

Hopefully that makes sense..

Comment: What do you mean by "the `df` name"? I don't understand the question, could you please post an example of expected output?

Comment: Create a dict for this

Comment: `{x : y for x , y in df.groupby('animal')}
`

Comment: I would guess this sort of manipulation isn't really necessary. What do you ultimately need to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the name of the new df"  - how do you give a DataFrame a name? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary:

```
animals = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    animals[row['animal']] = pd.DataFrame([dict(row)])
```

To print `Dog` data frame, I can do the following:

```
>> print(animals['Dog'])
  animal  age  reports   id
0    Dog    4        2  245
```